# Time Intervals SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to display different views on different times of day.

`ContentView2()` from 12:30 to 15:00.

`ContentView3()` from 15:00 to 18:30.

The problem here is, that when it is 15:30, ContentView2() will be opened instead of ContentView3().

```
let dateComps = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: Date())

    struct MainViewa: View {
        
        var body: some View {
            
            if (dateComps.hour! >= 12 && dateComps.minute! >= 30) && dateComps.hour! <= 15 {
                
                ContentView2()
                
            } else if dateComps.hour! >= 15 && (dateComps.hour! <= 18 && dateComps.minute! <= 30) {
                
                ContentView3()
                
            } else {
                
                ContentView1()
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the wrong logic in `if`, so "15:30" goes into `ContentView2`. The correct logic may look like this:

```
if (hours == 12 && minutes >= 30) || (hours > 12 && hours < 15) {
    ContentView2()
} else if (hours >= 15 && hours < 18) || (hours == 18 && minutes < 30) {
    ContentView3()
} else {
    ContentView1()
}
```

But I prefer using an other method: convert your values pair into a single value - in this case to day minutes, and use this value in `switch`: in this case you can use ranges which looks more readable to me:

```
var body: some View {
    switch hoursAndMinutesToMinutes(hours: dateComps.hour!, minutes: dateComps.minute!) {
    case hoursAndMinutesToMinutes(hours: 12, minutes: 30)...hoursAndMinutesToMinutes(hours: 14, minutes: 59):
        ContentView2()
    case hoursAndMinutesToMinutes(hours: 15, minutes: 00)...hoursAndMinutesToMinutes(hours: 18, minutes: 30):
        ContentView3()
    default:
        ContentView1()
    }
}

func hoursAndMinutesToMinutes(hours: Int, minutes: Int) -> Int {
    hours * 60 + minutes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `else`: so both `ContentView2()` and `ContentView3()` will appear independently.

Now, if you want `ContentView1()` to appear only when none of the others is there, it'd be better to create a couple more computed variables that can be combined for this purpose.

See example below:

```
let dateComps = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: Date())

struct MainView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        // Moved condition to a variable, see below
        if show1 {
            ContentView2()
        }
        
        // Not an "else", just a separate condition
        // Moved condition to a variable, see below
        if show2 {
            ContentView3()
        }
        
        // In case this view needs to appear when the others are not there
        if !show1 && !show2 {
            ContentView1()
        }
        
    }
    
    // Conditions
    private var show1: Bool {
        (dateComps.hour! >= 12 && dateComps.minute! >= 30) && dateComps.hour! <= 15
    }
    private var show2: Bool {
        dateComps.hour! >= 15 && (dateComps.hour! <= 18 && dateComps.minute! <= 30)
    }
    
}
```